# Can not control blutooth device's volume from ubuntu 22.04LTS

Tags: bluetooth, 22.04, volume-control

I have just upgraded my ubuntu to 22.04LTS and I have a problem controling volume on my bluetooth speaker.

When I increase or decrease the voulme the slider appears on the screen but nothing happens. I can only adjust the volume using the buttons on my bluetooth speaker now. Before upgrading to 22.04LTS I was able to control the volume level from both the device and my laptop.

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: One workaround is to disable the builtin audio via pavucontrol. Sometimes it switches but not always.

Comment: I removed pavucontrol using `sudo apt remove pavucontrol --purge`, but it didn't fix the problem in my case.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this is a spurious occurrence. One method I have found that fixes it is to restart the audio deamon with

```
systemctl --user restart wireplumber
```

When using the Spotify desktop app, it has to be restarted but at least the volume buttons then control the Bluetooth headset again instead of the laptop speakers. As a backup solution, `pavucontrol` is a tool that can set the volume of individual audio sinks including the Bluetooth audio output.

Comment: It seems like systemctl can't recognize wireplumber. Here is the output of the command you mentioned: `Failed to restart wireplumber.service: Unit wireplumber.service not found.` I have also tried pavucontrol to control the volume and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Check that it is installed with `sudo apt install wireplumber`. Although it should be installed by default...